# Doctrine Query expression to Collection expression

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to convert an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr to Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr

I have a query expression and i want to use it with \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria, the Collection criteria uses only Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr

Thank you

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve exactly?